# How to reserve database connections from a pool for a specific method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I'm using the `tomcat-jdbc` connection pool with  `spring` `@Transactional` methods.

Question: how can I reserve a fixed size of connections for a specific method? Means: other methods might throw an exception if the database connections are used up. But still a specific method should be able to execute with a fixed set of reserved database connections.

Like my `maxActive` connection limit is `100`, but I want to reserve `20` for a specific process. Thus other methods throw already an exception if 80 active connections are in use.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: Create a dedicated datasource, that is used only by that method...

Comment: I agree with Evgeni: create a second datasource and use only that inside that method